# Difference between /wc and /part in irssi IRC client

Tags: irssi

What is the difference between `/wc`(closes the current window) and `/part`(parting the channel) commands in `irssi` IRC client? I am aware that in some occasions `/part` does not close a window(for example if connection with IRC server is lost or if it is not a channel window which one tries to close), but in general, what is the difference between those two seemingly nearly identical commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One closes the window (/wc), the other parts the channel (/part). Closing the window will also part the channel, but you can't '/part' other windows :-).

"Using the /wc method is useful for parting channels on disconnected networks. In these cases, simply using /part will not work." - https://quadpoint.org/articles/irssi/#query-windows

## Documentation:

- PART: [Irssi Manual - 6.2 Joining, parting](http://www.irssi.org/documentation/manual)
- WC: [Startup HOWTO - 2. Basic user interface usage](http://irssi.org/beginner/#c2)

## Source code:

- PART: [src/irc/core/irc-commands.c](https://github.com/irssi/irssi/blob/master/src/irc/core/irc-commands.c) - - `/* SYNTAX: PART [<channels>] [<message>] */`
- WINDOW CLOSE: [src/fe-common/core/window-commands.c](https://github.com/irssi/irssi/blob/master/src/fe-common/core/window-commands.c) - `/* SYNTAX: WINDOW CLOSE [<first> [<last>]] */`
- WC: [/irssi/irssi.conf](https://github.com/irssi/irssi/blob/master/irssi.conf) - creates an alias `WC = "WINDOW CLOSE"`

Comment: Why do you say that you can't `/part` other windows? You can use `/part #channel` regardless of the window.

Comment: `/wc` will close any window. `/part` is a more elegant way to leave a channel. You generally don't `/part steve` or `/part status` :-). `/part` also won't work if you wish to close a window on a disconnected channel.

Comment: `/part` isn't particularly "elegant". It's just taking the arguments that you give it and turns it into a raw `PART #channel :Quit message` packet for the server.

Answer (score 3):

Also related: /set autoclose_windows. If you are using /wjoin, then /wc would close the window and part all the channels. With /part, you can part a single channel. Similarly, /query and /unquery (or /query in the query) can be used for private messages.